# Comparing test data and prediction outcome

Tags: r, regression, comparison

I trying Logistic regression on a dataset. I have successfully divided my dataset into train and test. The regression model also works fine however when I apply it on my test I only get an outcome for 393 observations when the length of my test dataset is 480. How can I compare and get the mismatch or find out what went wrong?

My data has no NAs.

I am trying to create a confusion matrix.

This is my code:

```
n=nrow(wine_log)
shuffled=wine_log[sample(n),]

train_indices=1:round(0.7*n)
test_indices=(round(0.7*n)+1):n

#Making a new dataset
train=shuffled[train_indices,]
test=shuffled[test_indices,]

wmodel = glm(final_take~., family = binomial, data=train)
summary(wmodel)

result1 = predict(wmodel, newdata = test, type = 'response')
result1 = ifelse(result > 0.5, 1, 0) - Can someone also explain how will removing this affect the outcome?
result1

> table(result1)
result1
  0   1 
255 138 
> table(test$final_take)

 Bad Good 
 418   62 

structure(list(fixed_acid = c(7.4, 7.8, 7.8, 11.2, 7.4, 7.4, 
7.9, 7.3, 7.8, 7.5), vol_acid = c(0.7, 0.88, 0.76, 0.28, 0.7, 
0.66, 0.6, 0.65, 0.58, 0.5), c_acid = c(0, 0, 0.04, 0.56, 0, 
0, 0.06, 0, 0.02, 0.36), res_sugar = c(1.9, 2.6, 2.3, 1.9, 1.9, 
1.8, 1.6, 1.2, 2, 6.1), chlorides = c(0.076, 0.098, 0.092, 0.075, 
0.076, 0.075, 0.069, 0.065, 0.073, 0.071), free_siox = c(11, 
25, 15, 17, 11, 13, 15, 15, 9, 17), total_diox = c(34, 67, 54, 
60, 34, 40, 59, 21, 18, 102), density = c(0.9978, 0.9968, 0.997, 
0.998, 0.9978, 0.9978, 0.9964, 0.9946, 0.9968, 0.9978), pH = c(3.51, 
3.2, 3.26, 3.16, 3.51, 3.51, 3.3, 3.39, 3.36, 3.35), sulphates = c(0.56, 
0.68, 0.65, 0.58, 0.56, 0.56, 0.46, 0.47, 0.57, 0.8), alcohol = c(9.4, 
9.8, 9.8, 9.8, 9.4, 9.4, 9.4, 10, 9.5, 10.5), final_take = structure(c(1L, 
1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 1L), .Label = c("Bad", "Good"
), class = "factor")), row.names = c(NA, -10L), class = c("spec_tbl_df", 
"tbl_df", "tbl", "data.frame"),
```

Comment: Can you please provide the data to make this code reproducible for us? Looks like we need `wine_log`. You can refer to this for help in getting us that data: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5963269/how-to-make-a-great-r-reproducible-example

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your line of code here:

```
result1 = ifelse(result > 0.5, 1, 0)
```

Should be referencing `result1` in the `ifelse` statement. I'm guessing that `result` is another object you have in your environment that isn't 480 rows.

So you should use this instead.

```
result1 = ifelse(result1 > 0.5, 1, 0)
```

You also asked what this line of code is doing. It's basically a threshold for your predictions from the `glm` model. If the prediction from the model is greater than 0.50, then you are translating the prediction to a "1". If it's less than or equal to 0.50 then you are translating that prediction to a "0". It's a way to convert a probability to a TRUE/FALSE or 1/0.